# SSL certificate domain to server issue

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

We have a server that holds a variety of our clients sites. For one client there is a ssl set up at a server level.

We want to add ssl certs to all out clients now.

We usually use cloudflare. However I am now getting the following error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Peer certificate CN=`*.[SERVER LEVEL SSL CLIENT]' did not match expected CN=`[CLOUDFLARE SSL CLIENT]'
```

when accessing the non server level ssl client over https.

Ive added the cloudflare origin certificate to the [CLOUDFLARE SSL CLIENT] ssl area in cpanel but that doesnt seem to be helping.

Are there any additional steps I need to take?